# Iterate through object

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I can't for the life of me, iterate through my models to show a table of my database.

here is where I do the request.

```
public function index()
    {
        $vehicles = vehicle::all();
        return view('vehicles', compact('vehicles'));
    }
```

And here is my view :

```
<table class ="vehicles-table">
  <tr>
    <td> id</td>
    <td> First Name</td>
    <td> Last Name</td>
    <td> Contact Number</td>
    <td> email</td>
    <td> manufacturer</td>
    <td> type</td>
    <td> year</td>
    <td> colour</td>
    <td> mileage</td>
  </tr>
@foreach($vehicles as $vehicle)
    @if($vehicle->soft_del == 1)
        @continue
    @endif
    <tr>
        @foreach($vehicle as $info)
            @if($loop->iteration >= 11)
                @break
            @endif
            <td> {{ $info }} </td>
        @endforeach
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

[Here is what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6iFm.png)

[Even though I get this in tinker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3reI.png)

How can I iterate through my vehicles effectively ?

Comment: What do you want to print in blade

Comment: As a sidenote, there's built in `softDeletes` for Laravel models, so it shouldn't be necessary to roll your own and worry about `@if($model->soft_del)` check. By default, if a Model in Laravel is deleted and has the `softDeletes` property enabled, it's `deleted_at` column will be updated in the database, and all queries used to fetch that model will ignore those records unless explicitly told *not* to do so (using `->withTrashed()`)

Comment: @TimLewis Thank you, I'll look that up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a mistake in how you implemented having a foreach loop inside of another foreach loop.

The first one is done correctly. When you call foreach($vehicles as $vehicle), it takes the $vehicles array and iterates through one Vehicle model at a time.

The second loop is where the error occurs. Calling foreach($vehicle as $info) is wrong, because you're treating $vehicles an array when it's a Vehicle model. Changing it to this should work:

```
@foreach( $vehicle->toArray() as $key => $value )
     <td> {{ $value }} </td>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining what was wrong with the way I tried to do this.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to iterate not only through each vehicle but also each field of each vehicle (which is not the right way to do this). You should explicitly call each field.

```
<table class ="vehicles-table">
  <tr>
    <td> id</td>
    <td> First Name</td>
    <td> Last Name</td>
    <td> Contact Number</td>
    <td> email</td>
    <td> manufacturer</td>
    <td> type</td>
    <td> year</td>
    <td> colour</td>
    <td> mileage</td>
  </tr>
@foreach($vehicles as $vehicle)
    @if($vehicle->soft_del == 1)
        @continue
    @endif
    <tr>
        <td> {{ $vehicle->id }} </td>
        <td> {{ $vehicle->first_name}} </td>
        <td> {{ $vehicle->last_name}} </td>
        <td> {{ $vehicle->contact_number }} </td>
        <td> {{ $vehicle->email }} </td>
        <td> {{ $vehicle->manufacturer }} </td>
        <td> {{ $vehicle->type }} </td>
        <td> {{ $vehicle->year }} </td>
        <td> {{ $vehicle->colour }} </td>
        <td> {{ $vehicle->mileage }} </td>
        <td> {{ $vehicle->id }} </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Otherwise, if you really want to go with iterating over your model use $vehicle->toArray().

```
@foreach($vehicles as $vehicle)
    @if($vehicle->soft_del == 1)
        @continue
    @endif
    <tr>
        @foreach($vehicle->toArray() as $info)
            @if($loop->iteration >= 11)
                @break
            @endif
            <td> {{ $info }} </td>
        @endforeach
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

***code is untested

Comment: Thank you ! the toArray() method is exactly what I was looking for